# Error in converting a .pdf file to .pcl via Ghostscript 9.53.3

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I am trying to convert a .pdf file to .pcl using Ghostscript v.9.53.3. This is the command I run from the Cmp Prompt:

gswin64.exe -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pxlcolor -soutputFile=C:\PCLprocessed\input.pdf output.pcl

However, I get the following error:

"GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3:Device pxlcolor requires an output file but no file was specified.
***Unable to open the initial device, quitting"

Also, when i try to run the following command, this error appears:

gswin64.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -dSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/NONE -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sOutputFile=C:\PDFtoprocess*.pdf C:\PCLprocessed*.pcl

"Undescoverable error: rangecheck in .putdevicecrops"

Can anyone explain why I get these error messages? I'm totally new to Ghostscript and i' m just trying to make this work for a job project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try -dAutoRotatePages=/None and -sOutputFile being careful about case. Using -dSAFER reading and writing to different directories can be a problem. I don't use Windows so am not sure about backslash versus forwardslash. Reading and writing to the current directory is not usually a problem.

Comment: You've want to convert a PDF to a PCL, but you've set "OutputFile" to the PDF. Also, OutputFile doesn't handle wildcards  - that probably the source of the error. Try: gswin64.exe -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pxlcolor -sOutputFile=output.pcl input.pdf